# Can we delete who

Tags: subjects, who

In sentences with *there is/are* and a relative clause such as these:

> 1. There is a man who(/that) speaks English.
> 2. There are some people who (/that) speak English.

Can we delete *who* (or *that*) to make the sentences like the ones below?

> 3. There is a man speaks English.
> 4. There are some people speak English.

Answer (score 1):

In standard Englishes we cannot delete *who* when it is the Subject of a relative clause. However, there *are* dialects of English where this is indeed possible. For these varieties sentences like the Original Poster's (3-4) are perfectly grammatical.